# Updating NSCalendar to Swift3

Tags: swift3

The following code, in Swift 1, throws the error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'Calendar'

```
class CyclicDay {
    lazy var baseline: NSDate? = {
        var components = NSDateComponents()
        components.day = 02
        components.month = 05
        components.year = 2018
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar.datefromComponents(components)
    }()
}
```

What are the Swift 3 equivalents of the NSDate and NSCalendar functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalents of `NSDate`, `NSDateComponents` & `NSCalendar` for **Swift 3** are:

- `Date`
- `DateComponents`
- `Calendar`

Actually every `(NS)Type` has equivalent `Type` in **Swift 3**.

Now in Swift 3, your code will look like this:

```
class CyclicDay {
    lazy var baseline: Date? = {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.day = 02
        components.month = 05
        components.year = 2018
        return Calendar.current.date(from: components)
    }()
}
```